# Getting material component error while migrating from Angular 9.1 to 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, mdc-components, angular15

I am new to Angular.
I recently migrated from 9.1 to 15.
Post that, did the mdc migration also as we have material changes in 15.
Now, while running `ng serve`, the compilation is getting failed and from the stack it seems to be issue with Material UI. But not able to figure out what to check here.

```
 ./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
   ╷
50 │   @if custom-properties.is-custom-prop-string($text-field-height) {
   │       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@material/textfield/_variables.scss 50:7                      get-outlined-label-position-y()
  node_modules/@material/textfield/_variables.scss 134:29                    @forward
  @material/_index.scss 1:1                                                  @use
  node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/_form-field-density.scss 4:1     @use
  node_modules/@angular/material/paginator/_paginator-theme.scss 10:1        @use
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/density/private/_all-density.scss 9:1  @forward
  @angular/_index.scss 18:1                                                  @use
  src/styles.scss 2:1                                                        root stylesheet
```

Also, in code base post mdc-migration, some TODO statements have been added to material-override.scss file.
What exactly does this line mean ?

```
.mat-p-bar-amber {
/* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of progress-bar that may no longer apply for the MDC version.*/
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette(mat.define-palette(mat.$amber-palette));
```

Any suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73206561/15439733